# Controlling a web browser using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, selenium-rc, webautomation

I have been assigned the task of automating a web based task ( for a HTTPS website). The users currently are filling in the Excel sheet with the data, they now want to automate excel in such a way that it directly controls the browser and fills in the data.

I found the iMacros Scripting edition as a possible solution for doing this, I wanted to know if there are any other similar tools which can be used for controlling the browser and filling in data.

I also had a look at the Selenium Client Driver, but I am not sure on how to use it in Excel VBA.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Plenty of examples out there if you google for "VBA automate IE" (also plenty of VB6 examples which should map almost unchanged to VBA). How familiar are you with web programming? That's really the biggest hurdle to accomplishing this type of task: it's easy to get a reference to the HTML document, but locating and manipulating objects within that is more tricky.

Comment: actually I am not very familiar with it. I think it will take quite a bit of figuring out on how to work with it. Any suggestions or tools which can help with the job?

Comment: If I need to do this I tend to use VBA, but only because that's what I'm familiar with.  Plenty of other languages and frameworks out there, and Google will point you to tons of examples. It's easier to give advice on specific problems, so you should just try out some simple examples and check back here if you have questions on the next steps.

Comment: @Darshan Bhatia: If you can share the link then I can post a sample. You can write to controls like Textboxes/Comboboxes etc in a web browser after you refer to them by their Element IDs.

Comment: @Siddharth: The website is internal and hence i would not be able to post the link.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Selenium from Visual Basic Editor by installing the tools provided here :

http://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/

There is a Selenium IDE plugin to automatically record a script in VBA and an installation package to run Selenium command in Visual Basic Editor.

The following example starts firefox, opens links in the 1st column, compares the title with the 2nd column and past the result in the 3rd column.
Used data are in a sheet, in a range named "MyValues".

```
Public Sub TC002()
   Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver, r As Range
   selenium.Start "firefox", "http://www.google.com" 
   For Each r In Range("MyValues").Rows
     selenium.open r.Cells(, 1)
     selenium.waitForNotTitle ""
     r.Cells(, 3) = selenium.verifyTitle(r.Cells(, 2))
   Next
   selenium.stop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This sample open stackoverflow site an show IE

```
Sub OpenIE()
'officevb.com
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "http://www.stackowerflow.com"

 'wait load
 While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
 Wend

ie.Visible = True

End Sub
```

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for reading data from excel and passin it to selenium for to do task like "click, select, close etc" and also you can write data to excel.

This is in python i don know VB and i do know perl if u wish i'll give same code in perl too.

i hop this may help.

```
from xlwt import Workbook

import xlrd

testconfigfilename="testconfig.xls"

    if (len(sys.argv) > 1):

        testconfigfilename=sys.argv[1]       

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(testconfigfilename);

    wb.sheet_names();

    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0); 'Sheet 0 - selenium server configuration'



    seleniumHost = sh.cell(1,0).value

    seleniumPort = int(sh.cell(1,1).value)

    testBaseURL = sh.cell(1,2).value

    browser = sh.cell(1,3).value

    timeout = int(sh.cell(1,4).value)

    path = sh.cell(1,5).value

outputwb = Workbook()

    outputsheet = outputwb.add_sheet("result",cell_overwrite_ok=True) #get the first sheet in the result xls 

outputsheet.write(RowNumber,colNumber,"data")
```