# excel macro downloaded data from web - tracking

Tags: excel, web, import, vba

my goal is to create macro which will allow me following:
1) copy number from cell 
2) go to ups tracking http://www.ups.com/tracking/tracking.html 
3) paste tracking number from cell 
4) submit tracking request 
5) copy the status of delivery into my excel sheet
6) move to next line and do same process

I wil much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done directly in VBA. At least, this seems complicated as it involves copying data in the right form, submiting a form and get a value from a webpage...

If I had to do that, I would do it using java, python or c# + a web library allowing to execute javascript (like selenium webdriver). Then, I would use a csv file as input & output.

[edit] actually Selenium can be used threw VBA : [Controlling a web browser using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489418/controlling-a-web-browser-using-excel-vba)